# USB Drive partition corrupted

Tags: partitioning, usb, disk

I was working with my usb drive when I plugged it in and in gparted and the usb showed unallocated partition and gparted asked me to create a partition table. I created a table and my pc got stuck and the process force killed. Now the usb isn't showing anywhere and if I run gparted /dev/sdc it shows a partition of 2.00 TiB and if I try to create partition table the terminal says :
/dev/sdc. Unrecognized label 
Input /output error during read on /dev/sdc
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc 
Error opening /dev/sdc: No medium found

Comment: It sounds like your USB drive is dead. They don't last forever, and I've never heard of one showing your symptoms being recovered. (That's not to say it's impossible, but if it is possible I've never heard of a success story.)

Answer (score 0):

The following could provide a solution if your usb drive uses a Linux filesystem. You will need to use the terminal.

First, make sure that you have unmounted your device.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdc
```

To check what kind of filesystem your device has, type in the following command:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
```

You will get a prompt that looks like this:

```
Command (m for help):
```

Next, you need to enter the `p` command. This will print the partition table for the device. At the bottom of the table, it should show you a range of fields that look roughly like this.

```
Device Boot    Start     End      Blocks    Id  System
/dev/sdc       2048   15158239    7578096   83  Linux
```

If your Id field says 83, and your System field says Linux, the following may help you. If not, I do not know how to solve your issue.

*Everything written beyond this point assumes your Id field is 83 and your System field is Linux*

You need to use the `fsck` command to repair your filesystem. If it is a Linux filesystem, it should have a directory called lost+found. This is where any recovered files will be stored.

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdc
```

Remount your device. Example:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/usr
```

If any of your files are recovered, you will find them in the lost+found directory of your usb drive.

Hope this was of some help.

Comment: Running fdisk shows fdisk: unable to open /dev/sdc: No medium found

Comment: Do you have any existing partitions on the drive? If so, what are they called?